# Unable to Validate Json Schema in rest assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I am using rest assured and validating JSON schema using it. I generated the schema using jsonschema.net(draft 7) and saved the generated schema in the file and matched the generated schema against the response of GET API.
But the code throwing the error with output like:

```
Actual: {"success":true,"message":"FacilityAttributes List","error":{},"result":[{"id":"aa2cdb2e-89cd-4970-a976-42df3349df74","name":"INTERNATIONAL","rank":null,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"BusinessType","description":"Please check if facility is international!"},{"id":"144e7c1c-9df4-4c65-ae7e-685013566731","name":"HEAVY","rank":null,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"BusinessType","description":"Please check if facility can handle heavy goods!"},{"id":"ca20c185-4c9a-425e-82e4-a5b244b5ef9d","name":"B2B","rank":5,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"BusinessType","description":null},{"id":"12a2c7f3-7da7-4682-953c-2e06ab8c8335","name":"B2C","rank":4,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"BusinessType","description":null},{"id":"34ef64ee-33dc-43ea-9ef0-722aeb2377f8","name":"HLD","rank":2,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"BusinessType","description":null},{"id":"5147ec36-59ac-4843-9f46-a881548e33aa","name":"dock_count","rank":null,"data_type":"INTEGER","default_value":"0","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Dock Door count in Facility!"},{"id":"1bdd7e0f-3a47-4d57-b641-439ba8790e48","name":"capacity","rank":null,"data_type":"INTEGER","default_value":"0","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Facility Capacity!"},{"id":"16e81b0c-fe3b-4827-bcf0-dbfd6f2cc386","name":"dimention_unit","rank":null,"data_type":"OPTION","default_value":"CM","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":["CM","IN"],"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Dimention unit on facility works!"},{"id":"75569bc1-f5f0-40c1-8e36-f3ef88940486","name":"weight_unit","rank":null,"data_type":"OPTION","default_value":"KG","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":["KG","GM","LB"],"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Weight unit on facility works!"},{"id":"48b121ba-e142-4f10-955c-12be4c33f787","name":"sort_code","rank":null,"data_type":"TEXT","default_value":null,"mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Facility sort code!"},{"id":"dc5cc52c-2f65-4b92-beaa-d8165dfdc157","name":"slab_rate","rank":null,"data_type":"FLOAT","default_value":"0","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Slab rate of facility"},{"id":"d6b3ac6d-5f97-46a5-8e71-72b96f2aa419","name":"slab_type","rank":null,"data_type":"OPTION","default_value":"Incentive Based","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":["Incentive Based","Fuel Based"],"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Attributes","description":"Slab rate of facility"},{"id":"03654f31-150f-4420-837c-f22bda1bc476","name":"ProductivityBenchmark","rank":null,"data_type":"INTEGER","default_value":"0","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Productivity","description":"Productivity Benchmark of facility!"},{"id":"ad471316-0858-4ed7-b817-7b554c780536","name":"ReverseDispatchCutoff","rank":null,"data_type":"TIME","default_value":"09:00","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Timings","description":"Reverse Dispatch Cutoff time"},{"id":"18041d87-a88d-4ed3-b457-9c6e96c2c250","name":"ForwardDispatchCutoff","rank":null,"data_type":"TIME","default_value":"12:00","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Facility Timings","description":"Forward Dispatch Cutoff time"},{"id":"c3e677a7-5b21-4c6b-8384-27c936720177","name":"Implant_enabled","rank":13,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check Implant is enabled in Facility!"},{"id":"0fcd0fbe-c448-455a-b825-8b1eb2fcc8b3","name":"DG_enabled","rank":12,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check DG is enabled in Facility!"},{"id":"34067f20-ece0-4775-8596-4447f74c5084","name":"FMODx_enabled","rank":11,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check Odx FM is enabled in Facility!"},{"id":"6237f744-e685-4aca-906a-48bd1bad9160","name":"FEApp_enabled","rank":9,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check FE App is enabled in Facility!"},{"id":"5ceb5fd0-74db-46fc-97a1-afbbaabc3686","name":"PayTM_enabled","rank":8,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if PayTM is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"f69817cb-8662-4f38-b44b-fb875703e9cd","name":"CardOnDelivery_enabled","rank":7,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if Card On Delivery is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"a3bcf54b-d734-4f95-92fd-a15bb2a00be3","name":"BagGuide_enabled","rank":6,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if BagGuide is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"19cfc5d1-f5fb-4666-a13f-7519588e3bb2","name":"LMOdx_enabled","rank":5,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if LMOdx is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"dc99d927-5925-4b09-a686-9c0231259337","name":"Constellation_enabled","rank":4,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if Constellation is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"41ba47fe-ec23-4649-bf0b-51101e631e68","name":"Bagging_enabled","rank":3,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if Bagging is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"7ead8afd-2e98-4330-8e15-40d4cb944a3c","name":"MidMile_enabled","rank":2,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if MidMile is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"4b9ffcab-b5df-4f19-bbd9-52e208168039","name":"Sorter_enabled","rank":1,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Please check if sorter is enabled in facility!"},{"id":"c81e981d-2c44-4bd7-9cc9-5ea20a3eaa3a","name":"Can_Handle_Palletised_Load","rank":null,"data_type":"BOOLEAN","default_value":"false","mandatory":false,"business_unit":"TRA","options":null,"facility_type":null,"group_name":"Flags","description":"Check if facility Can Handle Palletised Load"}]}

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:471)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:643)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.content(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:94)
at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$content$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:244)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:262)
at com.ums.api.AppTest.GetserData(AppTest.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

my genereated schema is [schema link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aeq3zqu1GwS8dw2AAOlX3-AUZyrjO3DMGRb0C3Iz7Es/edit?usp=sharing)

Repsonse of the api [API repsonse](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fWsngqSt5_JI8iPdi7m59WIaRgarrxRQ2jASC6topD0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @krishnan ,can you please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the current REST Assured library work until draft 4. I'm using json-schema-generator tool to generate json schema in draft 4 and able to validate the response.

Commands to install and generate schema: -

```
npm install -g json-schema-generator
json-schema-generator path/to/input_response.json -o path/to/json_schema.json
```

Reference links:
https://github.com/krg7880/json-schema-generator

Comment: @manaschopra - If my answer solved your issue, you can mark it as resolved :)